# How to assign a array to grid in extjs

Tags: extjs, grid

My extjs grid will be refresh after a few seconds with data loaded from server (thru jQuery). I am new to extjs. Please show me how to do that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ext comes with a lot of examples you'd be better off looking through those, especially the grid and ajax ones.